# HMS Interstitial Ads issue

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-ads

I am trying to implement Interstitial ads into my application When loading live Interstitial ads, I am getting error 3 and ads are not showing.
What might be the issue? Can you help on this.

Answer (score 1):

It is normal that some of the device would not show ,  the fill rate is not 100%.
Sometimes ads were loading on devices but not on each click sometime coming and sometime not, this is all related to fill rate is not 100 %.
Competitors Ads  also not having 100 % fill rate.